# textbox defocuses after pressing tab key followed by any character in Firefox

Tags: javascript, textbox, focus

I am trying to make an in-browser HTML editor, similar to CodePen and JSfiddle.I included a test to allow tabs without defocusing the editor. It works fine, except in Firefox. In Firefox, it keeps focus after pressing tab only to lose focus after the next keystroke.

```
let textbox = document.getElementById("preview-textbox");//textbox used for inserting HTML into iframe
    textbox.value = "";

let iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");//used to render user's code

    textbox.addEventListener("input", (e)=>{//inserts html from textbox into the iframe
        iframe.src = "data:text/html," + encodeURI(textbox.value);
    });
    textbox.addEventListener("keydown", (e)=>{//allows indentation with 'tab'
        let cursor_position = textbox.selectionStart;
        let is_tab = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if(is_tab === 9){
            textbox.value = textbox.value.substr(0, cursor_position) + '\t' + textbox.value.substr(cursor_position, textbox.value.length);
            let focus_textbox = setInterval(()=>{
                                            textbox.focus();//refocuses textbox
                                            textbox.selectionEnd = ++cursor_position;//sets cursor position
                                            clearInterval(focus_textbox);}, 30);//clear setInterval
        } 


    });
```

Comment: why are you using an interval?

Comment: intead of doing textbox.focus(); do e.preventDefault();

Comment: This worked. Much more simple than my implementation